# Extract a type from a param of a function declared in an interface

Tags: typescript

I have a function defined in an interface as following:

```
interface UseAutocompleteReturnValue {
...
getRootProps: (externalProps?: any) => React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>;
}
```

And in my interface I want to create a prop called `rootProp` which will be based on the type of the parameter `externalProps` in `getRootProps`, so the type in this case will be:

`rootProps?: any`

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use built in type `Parameters<T>` which returns parameters of given function:

```js
type GetRootPropsParameters = Parameters<UseAutocompleteReturnValue['getRootProps']>;
```

In this way, `GetRootPropsParameters` will be of type `[any?]`. You can of course get the first element with `[0]`:

```js
type FirstGetRootPropsParameter = Parameters<UseAutocompleteReturnValue['getRootProps']>[0];
```